# How to create/mutate a row using GraphQL where one field is a reference in Realm

Tags: realm, graphql

I've got the following (test) collections created in Realm:

**RoundType** (collection)

```
  uuid (string)
  name  (string)
```

*data in RoundType (1 row)*

```
uuid: 234dfg345dfg345    name: Fred Flintstone
```

---

**TestMutate** (collection)

```
 uuid (string)
 roundType  (RoundType)
```

*data in TestMutate: nothing, yet*

---

I want to CREATE a new row in TestMutate, where the "roundType" field in TestMutate is a reference to the ***existing*** RoundType row.

I tried the following in the hope that GraphQL knew the roundType existed but obviously that's not right.

```
mutation {
  result: addTestMutate(input: {uuid: "abc123", roundType: {id: "234dfg345dfg345"}}) {
        uuid   
  }
}
```

What's the correct syntax in GraphQL to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

its cool i got it. just use `**update**TestMutate(..)` instead of `addTestMutate` like so:

```
mutation {
    updateTestMutate(input: {uuid: "abc123", roundType: {id: "234dfg345dfg345"}}) {
    uuid
  }
}
```